# Upgrading CentOS from 6 to 7 has broken my boot sequence

Tags: centos, boot, kernel

I ran the upgrade assistant provided by CentOS for upgrading from CentOS 6 to 7. The upgrade appeared to have been a success, however my system now hangs when trying to boot up. (Keep in mind I have no physical access to this machine, it's a VPS)

[Here is a link to my machines /var/log/dmesg](http://hastebin.com/cepucewuco). I managed to get it through rescue mode, but I am unsure of what to do.

`cat /etc/redhat-release` results in `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)`

`ls -lah /boot` results in:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  171 May  8  2014 .vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.hmac
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  166 Jun 30  2014 .vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.hmac
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   43 May 29  2014 System.map -> /boot/System.map-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2.5M May  8  2014 System.map-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
-rw-------.  1 root root 2.8M Jun 30  2014 System.map-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2.6M May 17  2013 System.map-3.8.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64-vps
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 6.7M May 17  2013 bzImage-3.8.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64-vps
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 103K May  8  2014 config-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 120K Jun 30  2014 config-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4.0K Jul  8  2011 efi
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Feb 14 07:19 grub
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4.0K Feb 14 07:11 grub2
-rw-------.  1 root root  27M Feb 14 07:19 initramfs-0-rescue-4bc347e0a26e30479d94501100000018.img
-rw-------.  1 root root  16M May 29  2014 initramfs-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.img
-rw-------.  1 root root 8.6M Feb 14 07:19 initramfs-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.img
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  32M Feb 14 07:07 initramfs-redhat-upgrade-tool.img
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 573K Feb 14 07:19 initrd-plymouth.img
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 190K May  8  2014 symvers-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64.gz
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 224K Jun 30  2014 symvers-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.gz
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   40 May 29  2014 vmlinuz -> /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 4.7M Feb 14 07:19 vmlinuz-0-rescue-4bc347e0a26e30479d94501100000018
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 4.0M May 29  2014 vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 4.7M Jun 30  2014 vmlinuz-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 4.7M Jun 30  2014 vmlinuz-redhat-upgrade-tool
```

Here is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda1   /   ext3    errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota 0   1
/dev/sda2   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

I'm supposed to be running CentOS 7.

Comment: Are you able to get a shell at all, even in single user mode? If so, try setting "setenforce 0" and rebooting.

Comment: Can you share your /etc/fstab?

Comment: @MarkR. I cannot access any shell, the boot sequence always haults. However I manually turned it off and will attempt rebooting it now.

Comment: @JakovSosic I added my fstab.

Comment: Does your VPS provider documents supported versions and upgrade processes? There might be some information there. I had issues in a similar scenario already solved by the provider.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into something similar with a fresh install of CentOS 7 on a VPS.

The grub bootloader config file needed to be changed because it didn't include the line to load the kernel file. It was easy to figure out the missing line by looking at one of the fallback entries - you just need to make sure it's correct for the kernel version you're trying to run. I was able to boot up in rescue mode, make the change, and reboot successfully.

Config file at:
/boot/grub/crub.conf

Missing line looked like this on my machine:
initrd /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64.img

Comment: Should not it be `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` for CentOS 7?

Comment: On my CentOS 7 system /boot/grub2/grub.cfg is autogenerated and begins with "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE". Lots of stuff in there.  /boot/grub/grub.conf is a short text file for the bootloader screen options and changing it fixed the problem. This was on a fresh install less than a month ago.

Comment: Hmm...that means even after upgrading, it continued to use older grub instead of using grub2. I would never try to upgrade straight from 6 to 7 without reimaging though, even if that's supported. Sounds like asking for problem to me.

Comment: Mine was a fresh install, not an upgrade.